# Button Click using JQuery and C#

Tags: c#, jquery, button

I need to know if asp control (Button) is clicked or not using jQuery. This is button coding.

How can I pop up an alert box if someone hit a button using jQuery.

```
  <asp:Button ID="delete_checked_box_button_id"  OnClick="deletechecked_box_onclick" runat="server" Text="Delete Checked" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the `ClientIDMode` property to `Static` you can use the Id you set:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#delete_checked_box_button_id').on('click', function(e) { 
        alert('Button clicked');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#<%=delete_checked_box_button_id.ClientID %>').click(function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery, you can use the button's property onClientClick

[See this example in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BuyG2() {
        alert('Hai Jquery');
        }
</script>//jquery in sourse

 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "tmp", "<script type='text/javascript'>BuyG2();</script>", false);
}//ASP Button Click Event
```